# SELECT COUNT() returns ReadFailure after importing data from another cluster

Tags: import, cassandra

I've cloned one cluster to another with these steps:

1. Copy table files on each source node from /var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace/table/snapshots... to /location/snaps/
2. Run sstableloader on each source node.
3. Run nodetool import keyspace table /var/lib/cassandra... on each destination node.

After these steps I get this error when I try to run:

```
select count (*) from keyspace.table; 

ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures (UNKNOWN=[/10.100.100.2])" info={'consistency': 'ONE', 'required_responses': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'failures': 1, 'error_code_map': {'10.100.100.2': '0x0000'}}
```

Nodetool repair doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

A `ReadFailure` error is returned by the request coordinator when one of the replicas replies with a read error.

In my experience, this is almost always caused by a read request reaching the `tombstone_failure_threshold` (there were more than 100,000 tombstones scanned). You will need to check the logs on the offending node `10.100.100.2` to confirm it or it will otherwise provide clues for the failure.

As a side note, `COUNT()` doesn't scale in a distributed architecture and you're likely to run into a timeout because Cassandra took too long to count the records across all nodes. I've discussed it in detail in [Why is COUNT() bad in Cassandra?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314567/).

The [DataStax Bulk Loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkAbout.html) (DSBulk) tool has a `count` command which was written specifically for this purpose. DSBulk's `count` command overcomes the problems with the CQL `COUNT()` function by dividing the token range into small segments and performing a distributed count.

Here are some references with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- Docs - [Counting data example](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/dsbulkCountExamples.html)

DSBulk is fully open-source so it's free to use. Cheers!

Comment: I've tried  

select * from  keyspace.table limit 10;

and it returned 10 rows correctly. 

Thanks a lot!