# Getting ReadTimeout with COUNT() and AVG()

Tags: cassandra

```
ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node
    timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message=
    "Operation timed out for guitardb.active_line_status_new
    - received only 0 responses from 1 CL=ONE." info=
    {'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 
    'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

I have a table with 900,000 records while aggregation, count and avg between two timestamp values. I'm facing a ReadTimeout issue.

```
select sum(unit_price) AS line_total  
from active_line_status_new 
WHERE order_createts>='2022-10-01 00:00:00' 
AND order_createts<='2022-10-27 23:59:59'  
ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Here I have created index on order_createts column which is used in where clause as well. I have only one node in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the CQL query you ran but I assume you are doing an unbounded `SELECT` then aggregating the results.

If so, timeouts are expected when performing expensive queries which have a scatter-gather access pattern or the equivalent of a full table scan because Cassandra needs to retrieve ALL the partitions from ALL the nodes in order to aggregate them into a single result.

Cassandra is designed for high-velocity access, retrieving one partition at a time at very low latencies. Retrieving all the records of a table might work for a few thousand records on single-node clusters but it doesn't scale when (a) there are lots of partitions, (b) lots of nodes, or (c) both.

If you are interested, I've explained in more detail in [Why is COUNT() bad in Cassandra?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314567/). Cheers!